# Use todays date as a variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing

I need to create a load test script using Jmeter for the some apis including this one:

https://myserver01.net/alert/bydate/${Today}

Now I use the date value manually , e.g everyday I manually change the date value in the request , e.g today I sent a request to https://myserver01.net/alert/bydate/2018-02-09. I want to make it automated so that whenever I run the test it will take todays date by default. I have seen this answers in the link http://www.jmeter-archive.org/way-to-get-current-date-into-a-variable-td512937.html but did not understand the methods.  Like the first method says to define today in command line, which means I have to do it annually every time I initiate Jmeter. I want to avoid it and make it automated inside the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as using JMeter [__time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function:

> https://myserver01.net/alert/bydate/${__time(yyyy-MM-dd,)}

To test functions, you can use Function Helper Dialog which allows you to test:

[image: Function Helper Dialog]

Answer (score 4):

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element somewhere to your Test Plan
2. Add the following entry there:

   - Name: `Today`
   - Value: `${__groovy(new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'),)}`
3. Once done you will be able to refer today's date as `${Today}` where required

More information:

- [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation (explanation of `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern)